# How to Map a List as a Row with only 0 and 1 in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've created a DataFrame like the following

```
Index A B C D
```

if I am trying to add another list to the DataFrame as a row i.e. [A, B, C], are there any simple ways instead of using for-loop?

the expected result would be (notes: 1 represent that the elements exist in the list, 0 means not exist)

```
Index A B C D
0     1 1 1 0
```

Comment: So like add an extra row at the bottom? I'm a little confused because you don't have lists, you have a DataFrame of dummies (which really is a better way to store the data with pandas)

Comment: yeah, I am trying to add an extra row at the bottom.

Comment: So I simplify the coding problem I encountered. Regarding the question I have, C might not exist in some situations.

Comment: `df.append(pd.Series({i:1 for i in ['A','B','C']}).reindex(df.columns,fill_value=0).to_frame().T)` ?

Comment: Really Appreciate it. I have tried this method but wondering if there are better ways instead of for-loop.

Comment: well the for loop isnt of the dataframe. So i dont see any issues.

Comment: yeah, that's correct. just trying to optimize it a little bit -:)

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a row to a dataframe you can use loc .

```
nome_dataframe.loc[row_index] = list_vals
```

For example, if you have a dataframe with only one row( row index = 0 ), you can add the second row( row index = 1 ) in this way :

```
# create list 
list_vals_2row = [1,1,1,1,1]
# add list as a row 
dataframe.loc[1] = lista_vals_2row
# to see final dataframe
print( dataframe )
```